# Port pipeline to gst-rtsp-server

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to wrap this working sender side pipeline in the gst-rtsp-serve

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-plugin-path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/    filesrc location=sample.mp4    ! decodebin  name=mux mux.    ! queue    !  videoconvert ! edgedetect ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000  mux. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5001
```

Using a complementary pipeline at receiver side all the stuff work and I'm able to send a opencv processed stream, getting it at the client side. 
Something is wrong when I try to wrap part of this pipeline in the working example provided along with the gst-rtsp-server. 
Infact, editing the test-mp4.c and changing the filesrc input pipelin

```
"filesrc location=%s ! qtdemux name=d "
  "d. ! queue ! videoconvert ! edgedetect ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay pt=96 name=pay0 "
  "d. ! queue ! rtpmp4apay pt=97 name=pay1 " ")"
```

the sender doesn't work anymore. On the receiver side I got a 503 error since the receiver is unable to get the sdp. 
Could be this a iussue related to missing bad plugin directory?
I set it in the main Makefile but the problem still persists. 
I guess so sinche the rtsp-server works perfectly if I do not edit that line and my pipeline works good either.

Thanks,

Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it is an issue with the pipeline you have created. Try running your pipeline exactly how it is on the command line, but add fakesink elements on the end to see if that works:

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=%s ! qtdemux name=d d. ! queue ! videoconvert ! edgedetect ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay pt=96 name=pay0 ! fakesink d. ! queue ! rtpmp4apay pt=97 name=pay1 ! fakesink`

At a glance, it looks like you're demuxing the media, but not decoding the video to a raw format for the `edgedetect` element.

Comment: You pointed it right. I needed to decode the video stream after demuxing it!
So I replaced the qtdemux with the decodebin element and added an audioconvert in audio pipeline part! And it worked. 
Now I trying to mitigate the av sync delay at the client side :)
Many thanks :)